# Debug / log output from dbt python models

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Is there any way to view variables / output from python models in dbt? Currently my workaround involves replicating the python model in a jupyter notebook.

I found this in the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#limitations):

> **Lack of print() support.** The data platform runs and compiles your Python model without dbt's oversight. This means it doesn't display the output of commands such as print() in dbt's logs.

I tried adding print statements and python logging.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new feature (Public Preview) to collect logs from Python in Snowflake:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/logging-python

If you setup this correctly, then it's basic Python logging:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("python_logger")
logger.info("Logging from Python module.")

def do_things(session):
  logger.info("Logging from Python function start.")
```